# When I upload a rar or zip file using useForm, the type is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, react-hook-form

I use useform in form operations. If I upload an image, the types of files in the filelist are not empty, but when I upload zip or rar, the type is empty.I couldn't figure out if this error is caused by me or not.

I am sharing a few pieces of code to help you.

```
<Controller
                name="files"
                control={control}
                render={(fields) => (
                  <Button variant="text" component="label">
                    Select Files
                    <input
                      {...fields}
                      {...register("files")}
                      hidden
                      multiple
                      type="file"
                      accept=".zip,.rar"
                    />
                  </Button>
                )}
                rules={{ required: true }}
              />
              {errors.files && (
                <Typography marginTop={1} color="red" role="alert">
                  {errors.files?.message}
                </Typography>
              )}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>

        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
          <Button
            disabled={days + hours + minutes + seconds <= 0}
            onClick={() => {
              const values = getValues();
              Array.from(values.files).forEach((file) => {
                console.log(" ~ file: view.js:151 ~ Array.from ~ file", file);
              });
            }}
            form="challenge-form"
            variant="contained"
            type="submit"
            sx={{ mt: 3, ml: 1 }}
          >
            {" "}
            Upload
          </Button>
```

[image: logging files]